# Handle rapidly changing datasource for wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq

I have rapid incoming data (which are basically rows of a tabular data set). As i receive these rows, I merge/upsert them into the data cache. The data has to be shown on a WPF control (an item control).

**The problem** :
The data is not directly bound to the user control. A series of filter and grouping/aggregation (done using LINQ) is applied on the data before it is shown to the data. Thus what the user sees on the control can drastically change (say he changes the grouping, then all the rows will change).

This is what I am doing as of now :
As the data is coming in **VERY** rapidly, a thread is picking up the data every 2 seconds, applying the filter and then grouping the data and binding the data set to the wpf item control.
This is definitely not good as a new data table is being set as the datasource every 2 seconds. The application becomes laggy after some time.

What will be the best approach for me to solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: show your code so that someone may be able to recommend a method / approach to refactoring your existing logic.. can't really determine what's going on based on just reading your question alone..

Comment: It is a whole project. How much of code can I show here? If you could mention some specific part , I could provide that.

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? Every 2 seconds does not sound so bad. 
Are you sure you dont have a memory 'leak' somewhere? Because you say the application becomes laggy after some time, so it works at first but then suddenly becomes laggy

Comment: Hey @Dominik , The data is not much, a 1000 row by 100 columns at the very max, The frequency can get VERY high though. The data I am currently dealing with has about 300 rows. As the data comes in I update the datatable. After aggregating the rows further go down to about 100.

Comment: @Dominik, I think as I aggregate the data, every time a new instance of the datatable is created. This could be the reason for the memory leak. I am not sure how I could aggregate the data with out creating a new datatable object. I am trying to set up a sample program. May be then you guys can have a better look at the issue ?

Comment: @abhinav pandey Yes, if you do that we can definitely help you better. Now it is just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to approach this would be to create a [view source](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html) and bind the display element directly to that - that way you've got the grouping and filtering systems using the built in stuff.

I'd also then look into [virtualisation and optimisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will help with showing a lot of data.

As a more general note, I'd say explore whether you really need all that data to be displayed and at that frequency; it might be a better user experience (and easier on the machine) to aggregate the data and just surface pertinent details, that the user can then drill-down into further as required.